# calling sql from C++

Tags: c++, mysql

my c++ program has sql code in it, and it runs fine on one linux machine but on the other, I get the following error when I compile it

```
g++ test.cpp -o a -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient -lboost_date_time

fatal error: /usr/include/mysql/mysql.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I have mysql installed but I am obviously missing some step somewhere (on this machine with a new ubuntu installation)

can someone please let me know the fix. thx!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your computer doesn't have MySQL installed (in which case, install it), or is installed to a location other than `/usr/include/mysql/mysql.h` (in which case, change your compile command to point at the correct location)

Answer (score 1):

**You need to pass the location of `mysql` include files.**

You are passing library location with:

`-L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient`.

If you know where mysql headers are you need to pass them to compiler using:

`-I/path/to/directory/with/mysql/headers`

Comment: thanks stefanB and Ayjay, I just realized I had to install the mySQL headers....so, you both are right :-)